# Why do I get "could not load type" when using DesignInstance in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, designer

I have my XAML file declared as

```
<l:MoineauPumpCorrectionsWindowBase x:Class="WeinCad.Controls.View.MoineauPumpCorrectionsWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WeinCad.Controls.View"

        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WeinCad.Controls.ViewModel"
        Title="MoineauPumpCorrectionsWindow" Height="389.8" Width="538.2"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        mc:Ignorable="d"

        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:MoineauPumpCorrectionsViewModel
                         , d:IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    >
```

However I get the error

```
Warning 1   Could not load type

    '_.di16.WeinCad.Controls.WeinCadViewModelBase_MoineauPumpCorrectionsViewModel' 

from assembly 

    '_ExpressionDynamicAssembly_b102c6ac-1283-4a35-b5e2-4820bcb2588f
    , Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
      (WeinCad.Controls.ViewModel.MoineauPumpCorrectionsViewModel)

C:\.....\MoineauPumpCorrectionsWindow.xaml  
17  9   WeinCad.Controls
```

I am aware to load the type I should have a zero args constructor in my viewmodel as below

```
    public MoineauPumpCorrectionsViewModel() 
    : this(new MockIOService(), DesignCorrections)
    {
    }
```

but I still get the error.

Note that Resharper is still able to use the declaration to do static analysis on the XAML file but I don't get designer support for the view model.

Can anybody explain how to get rid of this error?

Comment: Try Set `d:IsDesignTimeCreatable` to `False`

Comment: Tried that. Didn't make a difference

Comment: I'm suspecting the `this` on the default constructor. Hm. I may be wrong.

Comment: Have you tried manually creating an instance of the object in XAML ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to reproduce this behaviour. I realise this is very late but might be helpful to future readers. Also, this applies to VS2013 but I assume VS2012 would behave similarly.

My markup on the root element was as follows

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vms:ClientViewModel}"
```

The WPF designer throws a "could not load type" exception every time. Note that my project is in its early stages so theres literally nothing special about the class

Based on @Aybe's comment I decided to try using a resource file as follows

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels">
  <vm:ClientViewModel x:Key="DesignTimeClientViewModel">
  </vm:ClientViewModel>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Adding a reference in the App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="/DesignTimeData/DesignTimeViewModels.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
```

And I then updated the root element binding like this

```
d:DataContext="{StaticResource DesignTimeClientViewModel}"
```

Using the static resource resolves the error without any other changes.